# How Can I Centralize Content Usage and Approval in a WordPress Multi-Site installation

Tags: multisite, admin

I am working with a non-profit client that runs several charities under one umbrella. A good metaphor would be to think of the United Way (but it's not the United Way).

Can a WordPress multi-site installation do the following:

Share content between sites. E.g., if site A has a section called "Advocacy", can that same content also be shown in site B? This would need to include text, photos, etc.

How centralized can administration be made? For example, can draft posts from all websites be approved in one location?

I'm sure there are other things I need to ask, but I'm still in the investigation phase.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't go with MU, but simply add categories and then run different css rules for that cat/site.

Comment: Not an answer but a comment: If you were to duplicate content across multiple domains (or even pages on a single domain), every site with that duplicate content could take a BIG hit from Google.y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) is the plugin you should use. I've been using this plugin in WPMS to share (and link) content between blogs, and it works well.

Basically, this plugin allows you to:

- duplicate a post from a blog to other blogs in the network
- options to create a link to those blogs, which means when the original post is changed, other copies are changed, too
- options to copy taxonomies, custom fields

Finally, the codebase of this plugin is good, so in case you want to change something, you can go through the code, change it like you want (this is what I'm doing).

Comment: yikes! You're editing the codebase for the plugin directly? How are you maintaining this when the plugin is updated? (edit: damn, I just saw this was from 2012!) lol

Comment: @Madivad Actually I rewrote the plugin for my needs. I removed redundant code and optimized it for specific cases. I don't need the new version or update anymore. But if you want to use this plugin without adding more stuffs, you can just download and use it (unfortunately, it doesn't have hooks to add more functionality).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://premium.wpmudev.org/.  There are many plugins and resources for what you are looking to do.  There is also a service called [ManageWP.com](http://ManageWP.com) that works well with a multi-site to manage it and post content.

The Wordpress codex has a function called switch_to_blog() found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) that allows you to switch to a certain site in your theme files to pull posts from that site and then switch back to the current site afterwords to continue with the usual content of the page.